# Focusing on textBox ScrollViewing issue- Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

Ok I write Windows Phone 7.5 application in which I have several textboxes in a single page. 
I made a ScrollViewer and inside I have a Grid and the textBoxes are inside the Grid. 
I want to make it so that when I press enter keyboard button in the textbox I will focus on the next textBox. 
So I made events in which I check whether enter button is clicked and if it is I focus on the next element, but when I focus on textBox which is even lower than the normal window and you have to scroll down to see it, it actually focuses on it but doesn't displays it and the screen stays on the last marked textbox.
Is there a way to fix that? Here is how I do it:

```
private void txtUsername_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                txtPassword.Focus();
            }
        }
```